# AngularJS object model intellisense in cshtml / html files?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, typescript

just wanted to confirm if that is possible -  to have object model intellisense in angular in cshtml ?
Like on this example, vm.form.Pages - a collection of PageModel objects defined in typescript/javascript file, intellisense works fine in typescript code.
How ever there is no intellisense in cshtml as u can see. Maybe there is a way to have such intellisense in cshtml/html files ??

[image]

Comment: No this does not work or seem possible. There has been some work for Intellisense and compile time safety for Angular2 templates.

Comment: thanks, thought so...